# MVC hides virtual directories in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the default directory in my IIS server set as an MVC 4 Razor application. I have it set up so that dynamic actions can be passed into the url. For example.

www.mydomain.com/4
www.mydomain.com/5

Basically those two launch accounts for users with id's of 4 and 5 respectively.

Works great.

But, I have a virtual directory on the same server called admin. I would hope that I could navigate to www.mydomain.com/admin but sadly MVC intercepts it and thinks that i'm looking up the user id of amdin.

Is there a way to poke holes in the route to allow for virtual directories?

Thanks in advance!

/Eric

########## adding my route

```
        //route for site root
        routes.MapRoute(
        "YourRouteName", // Route name
        "{flightNumber}/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", flightNumber = " " } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: What about accepting only number as a user Id since it is an ID? Then your `admin` wouldn't match the root and would be redirected to the virtual directory. If you need help with this, please post your route creation code.

Comment: OK. Route added. Sadly my id is actually a string, I just used a int to simplify my question. So, that said, with the above route, how could I redirect to my virtual?

Comment: In this case can you prefix your route? Let's say `"fn/{flightNumber}/{action}"`?

Answer (score 0):

You could constrain your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "YourRouteName",
    "{flightNumber}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    new { flightNumber = @"\d+" }
);
```

Now it is required that you must always have a `flightNumber` which is one or more digits followed by an optional controller action.

Thus `/5` will hit the `Index` action of `Home` controller and pass it `flightNumber = 5` parameter and `/5/admin` would hit the `Admin` action of `Home` controller passing it `flightNumber = 5` parameter.

Now if your ids are not integers but strings things will get complicated because the routing engine will no longer be able to disambiguate your routes. You could constrain the `action` part to a list of possible actions using a RegEx but find that approach a bit limiting because if someone adds a new action to the Home controller he would also need to update the route constraint.

Comment: Thanks Darin. My site has actions beyond the flight number so your suggestion is out. I need to have /<flightnumber>/home <flightnumber>/contact so I don't think looking for /<flightnumber>/admin will solve it.

I have to use strings as the lookup so that's the other problem. Agreed it would be easier if it was integers.

Comment: Yes, in this case I am afraid that you will have to rethink your route patterns.